# AWS Elastic beanstalk hook failed :- unable to copy file to c:/windows/fonts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have configured the elasticbeanstalk hook to download the file from s3 bucket to windows elasticbeanstalk instance.

file downloaded successfully on Desktop of administrator user of elasticbeanstalk, but I am unable to copy that file to c:/Windows/fonts directory.

below is the .config file.

```
sources:  
  "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop": https://test.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/font/ARIALUNI.zip
commands:
  copyfile: 
    command: copy C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ARIALUNI.TTF C:/Windows/Fonts
```

It's giving below error in elasticbeanstalk.

> Error occurred during build: Command copyfile failed
>   nfra-WriteRuntimeConfig, Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PreAppDeploy,
>   Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Hook-PostAppDeploy]
>   Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null.

I have also tried to hook file like but that doesn't work.

```
sources:  
  "c:/myproject/myapp": https://test.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/font/ARIALUNI.zip
```

It's giving below error in elasticbeanstalk.

> Error occurred during build: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or
>   filename: u'c:\Windows\Fonts\ARIALUNI.TTF'

Answer (score 0):

Updated config file with the below code and it works.

Refrence url : https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2008/03/20/special-folders/

```
sources:
  "c:/windows/temp/fonts": https://test.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/font/ARIALUNI.zip

files:
  "C:\\scripts\\install_font.ps1":
    content: |
      #Commands
      $Destination = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace(0x14)
      #Font Location
      $Font = "C:\Windows\Temp\Fonts\ARIALUNI.TTF"
      #Install
      $Destination.CopyHere($Font,0x10)

commands:
  install_font:
    command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\\scripts\\install_font.ps1"
    ignoreErrors: false
    waitAfterCompletion: 5
```